# iOS SQLite full text search example

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, fts3, fts4

I am trying to build an app that utilizes SQLite FTS. I found a very interesting post on how to do this just the way I want to. However, I am not a very experienced programmer at all and especially not in CoreData which is used in this post. Is there any example project that does something similar to what is described in this post? It would help me a great deal to see what is done in context. I'm sorry if this is a foolish question, I'm just still so new to all this. Thanks for any help with this!

Here is the link to the article: http://blog.lunatech.com/2013/01/24/ios-core-data-sqlite-full-text-search

Comment: Maybe http://swwritings.com/post/2013-04-30-searching-for-speedy-searching

Comment: @infobug what did you end up doing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, i had the same questioning before while i asked for FTS and FTC (full text completions).so i finally used FMDB which is a massive very useful lib that enabled me doing that,
this link is for you :

[FMDB link on github](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)
and
[Take a look here](http://www.adevelopingstory.com/blog/2013/04/adding-full-text-search-to-core-data.html) 
too